# Restore iPhone without updating the iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, icloud

So I have a older iPhone X running iOS 13.6.1. I changed the password and forget it today, I already have my data backed up. I was wondering if there was anyway I could erase the iPhone without updating. I got iCloud running on my computer and I got 3 choices, "Play Sound, Lost Mode, Erase iPhone" Would the last one update the ios?

By the way, the iPhone is not fully disabled, I still have 1 try left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Erase iPhone option will not update the OS.  It will simply wipe all data from your device.  You should be able to then setup the phone again.  However, without disabling FindMy, it will require you to enter your iCloud password, of course.

Comment: You won't be able to set it up again without updating it. Apple is no longer signing iOS 13.

Comment: I actually was able to set it up again with iOS 13.6.1!